# Set null/nothing to lookup field

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to set null/nothing to lookup field in crm 2011, using c# code. I'm using early bound entities.

My method has parameters:
public Guid ZalozeniPodporSmluvy(String name, Guid programid)

When i try to pass Guid - programid = Guid.Empty to EntityReference of programid property, i get error:

> Pgrlf_pojistna_smlouva With Id = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   Does Not Exist

The same i get when i try directly assign null -

```
pgrlf_programid = new EntityReference("pgrlf_program", null)
{
    supported_contracts PodporSmlouva = new supported_contracts()
    {
        name = name,
        programid = new EntityReference("program", programid),
    };

    PodporSmlouva.Id = _proxy.Create(PodporSmlouva);

    var entity = _proxy.Retrieve("supported_contracts", PodporSmlouva.Id, new ColumnSet(true));

    return entity.Id;
}
```

Sometimes i need to pass exact guid to this method and make a reference between two entities and sometimes not. How can i pass nothing to programid and create no reference?

Comment: in which line you are getting error?

Comment: in this line: PodporSmlouva.Id = _proxy.Create(PodporSmlouva);

Comment: is _proxy.Create method implemented by your side?

Comment: no, _proxy is OrganizationServiceProxy type where i define connection to CRM and Create is function of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
programid  = null;
```

If you want conditional do something like

```
if(condition staisfies){
programid  = null;
}else{
programid = new EntityReference("program", programid)
}
```